# Need advice on good way to filter out certain file names from Directory.GetFiles method in C#

Tags: c#, file, model-view-controller

In my MVC app I'm returning files from a file server into my view.

To simplify my problem: Let's say I have file1, file2, and file3 being returned from my Directory.GetFiles method. I've been instructed not to return file2, hence only showing file1 and file3 in my view.

Inevitably they'll come a time when rules change and file2 will need to be showed again. What would be the smartest way to keep a list of the currently filtered out files and check against that list? (without setting the files to "hidden"); One idea I could do is write the filename in a repository and cross check against it, but I'm just worried about creating a maintenance catastrophe...

is there a better solution im overlooking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
var ForbiddenList = new string[] {"file2"};

var Result = Directory.GetFiles().Except (ForbiddenList);
```

EDIT - as per comment:

Caching the result can be achieved rather easily...

```
var FullList = Directory.GetFiles ();
var ForbiddenList = new string[] {"file2"};
```

Then you can choose what to display - when you need to display all then just use `FullList`, when you need to display only the existing forbidden Files you could `FullList.Intersect (ForbiddenList)` and when you need to display all without the forbidden files you do `FullList.Except (ForbiddenList)` .

Comment: The questions seems to indicate caching the result of GetFiles. That does not require much change.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a configurable regular expression to filter the files. This has several advantages: you can exclude any pattern (such as a specific extension, or files starting with a specific string, or multiple files), and it is easy to maintain (maybe even via a web frontend).